# count items in a listbox from separate thread

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to get the count of items in a listbox from a separate thread. The equivalent of this: `count = listbox1.items.count;`

I know how to update the ListBox but from that I can't figure out how to count the items inside it.

I've done it, pretty simple actually:

```
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                delegate
                {
                    int c = lstLinks.Items.Count;
                    lblLinksCount.Text = c.ToString();
                }
                ));
```